# connect Kafka Cluster to Aws Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and my use case is I have provision Kafka 3node  cluster and if I produce the message in node1 it's automatically syncing in both node2 and node3 (mean I am consuming the msg in node2 and node3) so now i want that all the messages in another aws ec2 machine. how can i do that?

Comment: Is the second awc ec2 machine going to mirror the cluster you already have (and treat it as a distinct cluster), or is it going to host brokers that will be part of the existing cluster?

Comment: it's newly created ec2 machine in that i didn't install anything and it's not the part of the kafka cluster

Comment: Do you mean you want to expand your cluster to four nodes, and rebalance the data across them? Or, you want to create two standalone Kafka clusters?

Comment: hi I don't want to expand the cluster and I don't want the mirror of the cluster I just want that messages in another server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Kafka's MirrorMaker](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-replicator/mirrormaker.html) that facilitates Multi-datacentre replication. You can use it in order to copy data between two Kafka clusters.

> Data is read from topics in the origin cluster and written to a topic
>   with the same name in the destination cluster. You can run many such
>   mirroring processes to increase throughput and for fault-tolerance (if
>   one process dies, the others will take overs the additional load).
>
> The origin and destination clusters are completely independent
>   entities: they can have different numbers of partitions and the
>   offsets will not be the same. For this reason the mirror cluster is
>   not really intended as a fault-tolerance mechanism (as the consumer
>   position will be different). The MirrorMaker process will, however,
>   retain and use the message key for partitioning so order is preserved
>   on a per-key basis.

Another option (that requires licensing) is [Confluent Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-replicator/docs/index.html) that also handles topic configuration.

> The Confluent Replicator allows you to easily and reliably replicate
>   topics from one Kafka cluster to another. In addition to copying the
>   messages, this connector will create topics as needed preserving the
>   topic configuration in the source cluster. This includes preserving
>   the number of partitions, the replication factor, and any
>   configuration overrides specified for individual topics.

[Here's a quickstart tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-replicator/replicator-quickstart.html) that will help you to get started with Confluent Kafka Replicator.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, new machine is **not** a Kafka broker, so mirroring data to it wouldn't work.

> it's automatically syncing in both node2 and node3

Only if the replication factor is 3 or more

> mean I am consuming the msg in node2 and node3

Only if you have 3 or more partitions would you be consuming from all three nodes, since there's only one leader per partition, and all consume requests come from it

---

If you just run any consumer process on this new machine, you will get all messages from the existing cluster. If you planned on storing those messages for any particular reason, I would suggest looking into Kafka Connect S3 connector, then you can query an S3 bucket using Athena, for example